# Ошибка инициализации класса ( __init__() missing 1 required positional argument)

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, telegram

При попытке запуска скрипта, выжает ошибку = `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'`
Ответов на данный вопрос много, но я довольно глуповат, поэтому нужна помощь именно в моем случает.
Вот собственно сам код:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

class BOT_CONFIG:
    TOKEN = 'Мой токен'


class Parser:
    categories = ['tech', 'entertainment', 'economics','crypto','education',   'music','language','business','psychology','marketing','career','video','books','fitness','travel','art','beauty','health','gaming','food','news','blogs','sales','quotes','adult']

def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = 'https://tlgrm.ru/channels/'

def get_title(self):
    page = get(self.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('h3', {'class':'channel-card__title'})]
    for x in title:
        print(x)


parser = Parser()
parser.get_title()
```

Answer (score 0):

как вариант:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

class BOT_CONFIG:
    TOKEN = 'Мой токен'


class Parser:
    categories = ['tech', 'entertainment', 'economics','crypto','education',   'music','language','business','psychology','marketing','career','video','books','fitness','travel','art','beauty','health','gaming','food','news','blogs','sales','quotes','adult']

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url                             # - 'https://tlgrm.ru/channels/'

    def get_title(self):
        page = get(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        title = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('h3', {'class':'channel-card__title'})]
        for x in title:
            print(x)


parser = Parser('https://tlgrm.ru/channels/')       # + 'https://tlgrm.ru/channels/'
parser.get_title()
```